# wp_enqueue_style is not working

Tags: wordpress

I have a page that I want to apply custom css file, but I am having difficulty loading the custom css file for my page 'homepage'.  If anyone could help me out, it would be highly appreciated.  thank you!

This part works:

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles' );
function theme_enqueue_styles() {
wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/style.css');

}
```

this part does not :(

```
function addcssAndScripts() 
{
if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) )
{
    wp_enqueue_style( '/stylehome.css', get_stylesheet_uri() );
}
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addcssAndScripts');
```

Comment: Are you trying to load `style.css` in a child theme or `stylehome.css`? If the latter please confirm where that file is located.

Comment: Both the files are in the Child Theme folder.  Style.css is properly loading however stylehome.css isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're misunderstanding how `wp_enqueue_style` should be used.

In the example below the first argument I pass in is a handle, 'style-home'. The second argument is the path to the file.

```
function wpse_load_scripts_styles() {

    if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) ) { 
        wp_enqueue_style( 'style-home', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/stylehome.css' );
    }

}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse_load_scripts_styles' );
```

`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` gets the URL to your child theme folder. `get_template_directory_uri()` which is used in the first block of code in your question gets the path to the parent theme directory. Select the correct function based on where the file is located.

My guess would be that you've set the page, `homepage`, as your front page therefore you may want to replace the conditional with `is_front_page()`.

Replace:

```
if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) ) {
```

With:

```
if ( is_front_page() ) {
```

Finally `get_stylesheet_uri()` as used in the second block of code in your question will return the URL of the child theme's stylesheet (or the parent theme if you don't have a child theme setup).

Further reading: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style

Comment: Thanks, pleased I could help :)

Answer (score 1):

Will this work for you?

```
function addcssAndScripts() 
{
if ( is_page( 'homepage' ) )
{
    wp_enqueue_style( 'child-home-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri . '/stylehome.css');
}
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'addcssAndScripts');
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style